Sticky notes keep showing up on their own
I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I occasionally want to use sticky notes, but lately they are turning up without me installing them. I had to remove about a dozen of them that showed up on my second desktop a couple days ago. Is there some shortcut I don't know about that's doing this? When I want them, I use add widgets. Not really a huge problem, but it's getting annoying.
